# Issue faced in datepickerdialog

Tags: android, locale, datepickerdialog

My locale value is English or Hindi as selected by the user. But when I switch in between the languages in app, and open the datepickerdialog I get it like this :

[image]

What language is this, and why am I getting such language. When I don't switch it works perfectly fine.

Comment: you found any solution? Im also getting this issue with my app.

Comment: No, did not find any solution